# How to avoid dynamic cast in polymorphism with derived class of template type

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

I have this architecture(in short version):

```
class BaseBatch {
    virtual ~BaseBatch(){};
};

template<class T>
class Batch : public BaseBatch
{

    void draw(T* data) {
       do something..
    }
};

class BatchManager
{
private:
   static std::vector<BaseBatch*> batches;
public:

    template <class T>
    static void placeData(T* data){

        //Loop through the entire container
        bool found = false;
        for (auto&& b: batches())
            if (b->get_type() == typeid(T)) {

                dynamic_cast<Batch<T>*>(b)->draw(data);
                found = true;
            }

        //If no bach found, create a new One
        if (not found) {
            batches.push_back(new Batch<T>);
        }
    }
};
```

Problem is that the placeData function is called multiple (many) times per 1 loop and I think that the dynamic casting is a real pain for the performance but cannot figure out how can I solve this without using it. Is it really that problematic or I shouldn´t bother with it and keep using it? If i should avoid it, what would you suggest? Thanks

Comment: This design looks rather strange to me - can't you just have a `std::vector<Batch*>` instead? (or in addition to the other one) - especially since `dynamic_cast<Batch<T>*>(b)->draw(data);` potentially leads to UB (as `dynamc_cast` may return `nullptr` if it can't perform the cast)

Comment: Declare `draw` in `BaseBatch` as pure virtual.

Comment: You "*think*" it's a performance problem? That's just not good enough. You need to *measure* and you need to use a profiler to see where the *actual* performance problem is. It may (or may not) be where you expect; these things are tricky; always measure.

Comment: @UnholySheep I cannot as Batch is a template class, so need to know an argument before initializing it

Comment: @JesperJuhl You are probably right, without measures I cannot be 100% sure, but I would like to avoid dynamic casting, I´m just not confortable with it and till now I have been still dodging it succesfully

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `std::vector<Batch*>` use a `std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::unique_ptr<BaseBatch>>`. To access a batch use `batches.find(std::type_index(typeid(T)))`, then `static_cast` it to a `Batch<T>*`. `static_cast` has no runtime overhead. To create a new batch, use `std::type_index(typeid(T))` as the key.

The performance of `dynamic_cast` likely isn't the issue here. In fact, with this solution calling `typeid` is likely just as bad as `dynamic_cast`. The real potential gain is the lookup speed of the `unordered_map` vs iterating through every element of a who-knows-how-big `vector` and trying a `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Without actually *measuring* the performance you have no way to say that it will be faster. Don't just guess (or use prior experience) - *always* measure.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes I do. Because iterating through n items in vector trying a dynamic cast on each is definitely worse than an O(1) lookup of an unordered map, if n is at all big.

Comment: I know that. I'm not a complete imbecile. But, it's still a fact that the compiler often optimizes in surprising ways and one always needs to (follow the scientific method) measure ones results.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm not measuring this guys code. He can measure his current  solution and compare with my proposed solution. It's 100% counterproductive to SO to answer every single optimization question with "Go measure better, I don't believe you" when there is a good answer that probably improves the situation and will help people with a similar setup to this guy in the future.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you :)

Comment: you're welcome; it was never supposed to be a fight :-) I just tried to make a point - not measuring has bitten me multiple times in the past. One often gets surprised at what the compiler optimizes and when.